# brew install opencv3 apparently successful, but missing cv2.so and cv2.py

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, homebrew, opencv3.0

I'm trying to setup a working environment on my mac:

```
brew install opencv3 --c++11 --with-contrib --with-gphoto2 --with-python3
==> Installing opencv3 from homebrew/homebrew-science
```

...

```
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DCMAKE_INSTALL
==> make
==> make install
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

opencv3 and opencv install many of the same files.

Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
build variables:

    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0: 351 files, 110M, built in 5.4 minutes
```

So homebrew seems to think the install went well, but 
locate cv2.so finds nothing...

```
locate *cv*.so
```

finds only

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

and

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so
```

cv2.py or cv.py does not exist as well...
Any ideas?

Comment: It's not exactly the solution of your problem, but here it can help you: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/
I also had trouble installing the OpenCV in Python.

Comment: Do you need OpenCV 3.0? If you can live with the previous OpenCV 2.4.x series you can use 'brew install opencv' to get cv2.so and cv.py (I just checked with a 'brew ls --verbose opencv' on my mac).

Comment: @RevJohn This is what I use for now.... hopefully the Opencv3 brew repo would get fixed sometime soon, since I want to try the new feature extraction algorithms.

Comment: Actually with `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` in my `$PYTHONPATH` I can `import cv2` just fine with only the shared object...

Answer (score 1):

ive seen this error before using raspian, its also seen in ubuntu, renaming `cv2.cpython-35m-darwin.so` to `cv2.so` may help fix the issue.

ive heard it just a standard naming error.